# How Oauth2 server-side code flow should redirect back to user agent with the token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token

On all OAuth2 documentations i looked, including the [Oauth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1), the Oauth2 Authorization Code flow ends in the point where the server side holds both the refresh and access tokens.

**As a server-side of a web app, what I wish is to not finish the flow here, but response my web user agent with the access\refresh tokens**

- This in order to have my user agent later make calls to my app's server-side APIs using the access token for auth (the app's server-side will verify the token against the authorization server).

The implicit flow might be the flow i should have been using here (right?), but the authorization server in my company supports only the authorization code flow (and not the implicit flow) for now.

I thought of adding a redirect url as a query param inside of the redirect url of the authorization API.
This way, when the authorization flow will ends, and my app's server side will get the tokens, **it will redirect back to the User agent's url, providing the access\refresh tokens as hash fragments**

Is it safe for the server-side to redirect to user agent with the tokens this way?

Is there any better practice for redirect back to the user agent?